# Numpy operations on a subset of indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do "something" with two numpy vectors a,b and fill a matrix C in such a way, that C [i,j] equals b[j]-a[i], **but only for a given subset of j indices.** (At least that is the simple example I'm tring to break my problem down to).

I can do that using conventional for loops, but this is rather slow:

```
import numpy as np

n=1000
a=np.random.rand(n)
b=np.random.rand(n)
C=np.zeros(n,n)
allowed_j_indices=[10,20,34,100]

for i in range(0,len(a)):
   for j in allowed_j_indices:
      C[i,j]=b[j]-a[i]
```

I can also use numpy broadcasting like:

```
C=b[None,:]-a[:,None]
```

but although it is more efficient, for a very large number of elements (n>>1000) this actually becomes slower (and more memory intensive) than the simple for loop, since that one only loops over the elements in *allowed_j_indices*.

So my question is: Is there a way to combine both worlds, so that the loop is carried out efficiently with build-in functions, but also makes use of the fact that only a small subset of indices is neccessary?

**Important addition**: Assume that *allowed_j_indices* depends on *i*!

Comment: What is the operation you are trying to do (matrix multiplication, etc) ? Maybe it's already defined in the Numpy library

Comment: In this example it is simple subtraction, but in other application parts it could also be multiplication. The point is, that the library functions are getting worse than the for loop for large matrices, since I don't know how to incorporate the restricted set of indices to do that operation for.

Comment: `b[None,allowed_j_indices]-a[:,None]` is the best option IMO.

Comment: I should have clarified that the allowed_j_indices array typically depends on i. I just removed that to simplify the example, but realize now that is an important factor. Therefore you suggested solution would not work in my case. :(

Answer (score 0):

Trying to take your latest addition into account

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    j = allowed_j_indices(i)
    C[i,j]=b[j]-a[i]
```

Iteration `i` may still be required, but `j` should work on a whole row.

If `j = allow_j_indices` is a fixed array, applicable to all rows, then

```
C[: j] = b[j]-a[:,None]
```

should do.